# Coffeescript equivalent to Python's getattr

Tags: javascript, python, coffeescript

In python I can put a function into a variable at runtime, then call it using the getattr function

```
method = getattr(self,self.name)
method()
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Coffeescript?
Thanks!

---

Using zeekay suggestion but using classes would be:

```
class Test
   foo: -> alert 'foo'
   foo2: methodName -> this[methodName]()

x = new Test
x.foo2('foo')
```

Comment: With a workaround, yes. In Python, an instance method is bound to the instance, but in Javascript they are not. See http://www.s-anand.net/blog/bound-methods-in-javascript/ for more information.

Comment: Okay, see my answer and try this with the fat arrow: `=>`

Comment: `foo2: methodName -> this[methodName]()` is not what you want. It's equivalent to `foo2: methodName(-> this[methodName]())`. That is, it passes the function `-> this[methodName]()` to a function called `methodName`, then assigns the result to the `foo2` prototype property of the `Test` class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Javascript objects are associative arrays, and you can access property/methods using the name of the property as the key:

```
obj =
  method: -> 'xxx'
method = obj['method']
method() # 'xxx'
```

Your updated example doesn't work because `foo2` is merely returning `foo`. You might want to try this:

```
class Test
   foo: -> alert 'foo'
   foo2: -> this['foo']() # or @['foo']()

x = new Test
x.foo2()
```

Answer (score 2):

Objects and classes in CoffeeScript work very differently from how they work in Python. This can be frustrating, but the aim of CoffeeScript is to stay as close to JavaScript as possible, rather than adding a thick layer of abstraction. So, a few things to keep in mind:

1. As zeekay answered, `x[y]` is equivalent to `getattr`/`setattr` (except that it returns `undefined` if `x` has no property with key `y`, rather than throwing an exception);
2. Functions you attach to a class using the syntax `foo: -> ...` are just methods of the class' prototype, and can be modified at any time (or overridden on a particular instance).
3. After running `method = x.method`, there's one crucial difference between `x.method()` and `method()`, even though both run the same function: When you run the function as `x.method()`, `this` points to `x`; but when you run it as `method()`, `this` points to the global object (`window` in the browser, `global` in Node.js).

Check out my book, [CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript), if you'd like to learn more. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `foo2` returns the `foo` method intead of calling it. Change

```
return this['foo'];
```

to:

```
this['foo']();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a yes, but you have to use the fat arrow operator in the method definition:

```
class O
    method2 =>
        console.log(this)
```

If I understand this correctly, that syntax tells coffeescript to bind the instance to the method, allowing it to be called from outside the instance. If you use the thin arrow, coffeescript does *not* keep track of binding information, resulting in Javascript pointing `this` at something unexpected if you don't call the method via the instance.

```
class O
    method2 ->
        console.log(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test
   foo: -> alert 'foo'
   foo2: -> this['foo']
```

When you call `x.foo2()` it's not doing what you think it's doing.

```
-> this['foo']
```

This function returns the value of `this['foo']` which is a function object.  So the return value is a function object.  It doesn't run the function.

Try this:

```
class Test
   foo: -> alert 'foo'
   foo2: -> this['foo']()
```

Now when call `foo2()` it get the funciton object *and executes it*.

---

Also though, you only need the bracket notation when using a dynamic string as an accessor.  This is the exactly the same thing:

```
class Test
   foo: -> alert 'foo'
   foo2: -> @foo()
```